# Merge multiple intervals by splitting

Tags: arrays, algorithm, linked-list, intervals

There're two arrays: `regular_events` and `special_events`. Each of them contains multiple arrays, which present as `[start_time, end_time]`

```py
// Only one event, starts from 5:00 to 10:00
regular_events = [[5, 10]] 

// First event starts from 0:00 to 3:00, and second event starts from 12:00 to 15:00
special_events = [[0, 3], [12, 15]]
```

I want to implemnt a function `SplitMerge` to merge these events.

There're some rules for merging:

1. If there's no overlapping events, it will be merged.
2. If `special_events` is overlapping `regular_events`, the `special_events` will be keep, and `regular_events` will be increased or splitted.
3. `special_events` are not overlapping with each other.
4. `regular_events` are not overlapping with each other.
5. `regular_events` and `special_events` are sorted by `start_time`

For some example:

1. Non overlapping:

   - Input: `regular_events = [[5,10]]`, `special_events = [[0,3],[11,15]]`
   - Output: `[[0,3],[5,10],[11,15]]`
   - Explanation: The `special_events` and `regular_events` are not overlapping with each other, merge them as result.
2. Partially overlapping:

   - Input: `regular_events = [[5,10]]`, `special_events = [[3,7],[9,12]]`
   - Output: `[[3,7],[7,9],[9,12]]`
   - Explanation: The `special_events[0]` and `special_events[1]` is partially overlapping with `regular_events[0]`, decrease the `regular_events[0]` to `[7,9]` as result
3. Fully overlapping:

   - Input: `regular_events = [[5,10]]`, `special_events = [[7,8]]`
   - Output: `[[5,7],[7,8],[8,10]`
   - Explanation: The `special_events[0]` is fully overlapping on `regular_events[0]`, it split `regular_events` to `[[5,7],[8,10]]` and merge `[[7,8]]` as result.
4. Cross overlapping:

   - Input: `regular_events = [[5,10], [12,15]]`, `special_events = [[8,14]]`
   - Output: `[[5,8],[8,14],[14,15]]`
   - Explanation: The `special_events[0]` is partially overlapping both `regular_events[0]` and `regular_events[1]`, it decrease `regular_events` and merge as result.

I've tried solve it by slice (in Go) and Linked List (in Python), but not in use.

I also asked GitHub Copilot Chat, it gaves the answer:

```py
def SplitMerge(events, special_events):
    merged = []
    i, j = 0, 0
    while i < len(events) and j < len(special_events):
        if events[i][1] <= special_events[j][0]:
            merged.append(events[i])
            i += 1
        elif events[i][0] >= special_events[j][1]:
            merged.append(special_events[j])
            j += 1
        else:
            if events[i][0] < special_events[j][0]:
                merged.append([events[i][0], special_events[j][0]])
            if events[i][1] > special_events[j][1]:
                merged.append([special_events[j][1], events[i][1]])
            i += 1
    while i < len(events):
        merged.append(events[i])
        i += 1
    while j < len(special_events):
        merged.append(special_events[j])
        j += 1
    return merged
```

But it didn't work in case 2: Partially overlapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider the next implementation

`evs` holds sorted time points with event type

`state` remembers active events

```
def SplitMerge(events, special_events):
    evs = []
    for e in events:
        evs.append((e[0], 2))
        evs.append((e[1], 0))
    for s in special_events:
        evs.append((s[0], 3))
        evs.append((s[1], 1))
    evs.sort()
    #print(evs)
    merged = []
    state = 0
    for ev in evs:

        if ev[1] == 2:    #regular start
            last_reg = ev[0]
            state |= 2

        elif ev[1] == 3:   #special start
            if (state == 2) and (ev[0] > last_reg):
                merged.append([last_reg, ev[0]])
            last_spec = ev[0]
            state |= 1

        elif ev[1] == 0:    #regular end
            if state == 2:
                merged.append([last_reg, ev[0]])
            state &= 1       #clear regular bit

        else: #1     #special end
            merged.append([last_spec, ev[0]])
            if (state & 2):
                last_reg = ev[0]
            state &= 2      #clear special bit
    return merged

regular_events = [[5,10]]
special_events = [[0,3],[11,15]]

regular_events = [[5,10]]
special_events = [[3,7],[9,12]]

#regular_events = [[5,10]]
#special_events = [[7,8]]

#regular_events = [[5,10], [12,15]]
#special_events = [[8,14]]

print(SplitMerge(regular_events, special_events))
```

Comment: If there're the same star_time in regular and special events, it could return a unit duration by this algorithm.
regular_events = [[5,8]]; special_events = [[5,8]], and result as [[5,5],[5,8]]

Comment: Correction for such case: `elif ev[1] == 3:  if state == 2 and ev[0] > last_reg:`